# Wordpress - Hooks for Validation Data before User Registration

Tags: wordpress

I wonder if there is a wordpress hook to check a custom input field. When I add a new user and when I update a existing user.

If any fields are invalid I don't want the user to be created.

if(!is_numeric($_POST['phone_number'])) $errors->add('ERROR 0001', 'Invalid Cellphone Number!');

Also if exists it's compatible with Wordpress Multisite?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I'm developing custom registration, login, network-wide user profiles (one-blog and shared) etc. for a large custom project. In the process I had many sleepless nights figuring out stuff like this. Finally, I ended up with my custom server-side validation which is triggered from frontend via ajax calls. So, validation works on front-end as you type, but even if user has javascript disabled, he gets plain old submit and server-side validation (which is pretty easy to do).

The best hook for checking GET/POST submitted data is `init` - it runs always, it runs early (before any headers or output sent). For more specific tasks you may need other hooks, which are run later - `plugins_loaded`, `registration_errors`, for example.

See more here - http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/wordpress-initialization-hooks-benefits-and-common-mistakes--wp-34427

And here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117440/how-to-hook-into-user-registration-process-before-user-registers

Answer (score 0):

Adding user in wordpress already have validation but still there is no validation for firstname and last name and website
this can be achieved by following way
try this validation,
make plugin and add jquery and style will run only at admin section by

now in script file

```
<script>
    jquery(document).ready(function(){
var firstname=/^([a-zA-Z]{3,16})$/;
var lastname=/^([a-zA-Z]{3,16})$/;
var website=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

        $('.fname').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(){

            if (!$(this).val().match(firstname)) {
                $('.fname').removeClass('hidden');
             $('.fname').addClass('warn');


            }
            else{
                   $('.fname').removeClass('warn');
                $('.fname').addClass('hidden');
            }
            $('.fname').show();
        });
        $('.lname').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(){

            if (!$(this).val().match(lastname)) {
                $('.lname').removeClass('hidden');
             $('.lname').addClass('warn');


            }
            else{
                   $('.lname').removeClass('warn');
                $('.lname').addClass('hidden');
            }
            $('.lname').show();
        });
         $('.eemail').on('keypress keydown keyup',function(){

            if (!$(this).val().match(website)) {
                $('.eemail').removeClass('hidden');
             $('.eemail').addClass('warn');


            }
            else{
                   $('.eemail').removeClass('warn');
                $('.eemail').addClass('hidden');
            }
            $('.eemail').show();

            });

          $('.btn-1').click(function(){
          if ( !$('.fname').hasClass('hidden') ||  !$('.eemail').hasClass('hidden') ||  !$('.lname').hasClass('hidden')) {
           alert("Please check if any field is invalid!!");
          }
          });

}); 
</script>

in css file
<style type="text/css">
.warn {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: #fcc; 
}
.hidden {
   visibility:hidden;
}
.validationError {
            border: solid 2px red;
        }
        .validationValid {
            border:  solid 2px green;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi, I already have a script to check my custom fields. But I was wonder if for some reason the script fail, exists a hook to check $_POST variables by php before the user is created?  

I use the hook 'user_register' to save my custom data, but by that point if exists mistake in one custom field i can reject the isertion in my DB custom table but wordpress already register the user and I can't show a error message to the user.

Comment: Hi, i tried to find how to disable creating new user but from wordpress main files it is possible. By finding from where wordpress display error if name is repeating or email is invalid there code to check for other inputs can be added.

Comment: So you're saying that I have to change the wordpress user registration files? 
In this moment there aren't any hook solution?!

I will see that option.

Ok Thank you very much.

Comment: Validate your data long before it hits `create_user` function. Only if data is valid - proceed to user creation. See my answer above, ask amything if smth is unclear